# Autolayout Constraints Priority

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have 2 `UILabel` `labelA` and `labelB` and a width of 320 px. I created constraints

`H:|-[labelA]-(>=4)-[labelB]-|`

Unfortunately, `labelA` and `labelB` can sometime be big and would not fit without truncation.  I would like to make sure that no matter what, `labelB` will not get truncated. (`labelB` will not go over 160 px). However, I would like to use the available space for labelA as much as possible so fixing labelB to half is just a waste of space.

**Question:** How do I put a priority such that `labelB` always retain its intrinsic size? Where as `labelA` can get truncated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You set the content compression resistance to high on label B:

```
[labelB setContentCompressionResistancePriority: UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
```

This means that B will try not to be compressed below the intrinsic size given by the text. To make it also be as small as possible, you may also want to set the `contentHuggingPriority`- this will make it try to match the size of the text.

Comment: Awesome answer, works like a charm! ContentHugging is probably best used in vertical, since label hugs the text on the horizontal pretty well. That is not really a concern but +1 for pointing it out!

Comment: Hugging helps with multiple labels side by side, I find.